# Определить 37 байт памяти, повторяя последовательность (1,0,2,0,1,0,2,...)

Tags: ассемблер

Определить 37 байт памяти, повторяя последовательность (1,0,2,0,1,0,2,...)

Задание на экзамене по системному программированию, мне надо просто описать как бы я сделал, либо просто код

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Например так (я не вижу, чтобы в условиях задачи это было запрещено):

```
db 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1
```

Но если серьезно, то так:

```
db 9 dup (1, 0, 2, 0), 1
```

- 9 раз повторить последовательность `1, 0, 2, 0` (36 байт), в конце добавить 1:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]